# Any Java graphics library library with NURBS, homogeneous coordinates and perspective?

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, 2d, nurbs

Are there any Java graphics libraries which support NURBS, homogeneous coordinates and perspective transform?

I need 2D.

Better if this library will be an extension of something standard like `java.awt.geom`.